# Can't move object except on a single keyframe

Tags: animation

I have a downloadeded blend file. The objects within it can be moved only when the timeline is on the first frame. What can I do to make them movable on any frame.
Note: The Affect only options are all unchecked and snapping is disabled.

Comment: Actually it is possible to keyframe the translation locks. Maybe they are locked from the second frame on?

Comment: since you are new here it is a good idea to provide your blend file so we can check it out...

Comment: @Chris I have downloaded it from blendswap, so can't share it here due to copyright. But you can download it directly from: https://www.blendswap.com/blend/25425. The body parts of the fish are separate objects. Try moving on of them other than torso on any frame other than 1.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann No I checked that. There is no transition lock on the frames where the objects can't be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Found that the objects have actually cloth simulations applied, they can be moved if the cloth simulation is removed :)